# How to add new custom option type in Magento 2?

Tags: custom-options, magento-2.1

I want to create a new custom option type. When i go to the back-end, select a product, go to the section called "Custom Options" I can add a new option, at which point I can select the type of the option. I want to expand this list to include a new type of my own creation.

I can't seem to find anything about this for Magento 2, but I did find some good tutorials for Magento 1.

Comment: What custom option value do you want to add to the magento 2 base ?is it going to be a dropdown or text field?

Comment: @robin It would be an extended version of the radio custom option type.

Comment: Are u solve this? can u help me